# Как импортировать SOCKS5 прокси в Go>

Tags: golang

Как я могу защищено подключиться к прокси-серверу SOCKS5, есть код на подключение обычных http прокси серверов:

```golang
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(proxyS)
httpClient := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)},

}
```

Для SOCKS5 примеров кода не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Как написано в [документации](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.Proxy):

> ```
> // The proxy type is determined by the URL scheme. "http"
> // and "socks5" are supported. If the scheme is empty,
> // "http" is assumed.
> ```

Таким образом, ваш `proxyURL` должен быть вида

```
socks5://1.2.3.4:1080
```